# Is there an "about:config" (Firefox) In Google's Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser

Anything similar to `"about:config`" (Firefox) In Google's Chrome ?

Comment: The accepted answer is (very) out of date on this now.  `chrome://flags` is pretty much what you're looking for.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no about:config at the moment.

the [feature request on chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=16362) was closed on July 22nd with the status WontFix so you'll probably have to keep bumping the original feature request or open a new request [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues) with additional ideas or features than the previous.

Comment: `about:config` - is it feature available in chrome now ?

Comment: @Hitesh No, it is still unavailable. Although you will never get the amount of customization in Chrome that you will have with about:config in Firefox, Chrome://flags might be of use in Chrome.

Comment: why this is an accepted answer, while there is another  better answer?

Comment: chrome://about for those unwilling to scroll down

Answer (score 161):

Yes, and no. If by `about:config`, you mean "special page that lets you configure secret stuff, then it's there, and you can access it through `about:flags`.

If you want the complete list of pages available on Chrome, try `about:about`.

Comment: Nice. And not mentioned on [Google's old blog post](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/09/google-chromes-about-pages.html).

Comment: Was looking for a way to disable DASH (media source) in Chrome, finally found your answer here. Saved my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 51):

Using `about:about` converts to **`chrome://about`** which consists of **ALL** settings pages available for Chrome:

[image: chrome://about page]

Additionally, you should check the `about:flags` too.

Comment: Confirmed; working on Chrome 23.0.1271.95. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: useful stuff, but still no settings for mouse (like mousewheel speed/acceleration etc.) :/

Comment: Still working on Chrome 78. The most useful answer out of all.

Answer (score 37):

On a Google Support forums question entitled *"Is there an about:config"*, on July 10, 2009, user "PatrickB1991" responded with the following:

> No, currently there is no about:config page...
>   But **you can vote** for
>   http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=16362
>   and hope it will get implemented sometimes.

Comment: Your comment is poorly written -- as if Google Support wrote a page titled "Is there an about:config?" with Google seemingly telling people they can vote for it. None of it is the case. Your markup just makes it appear so. Google hasn't encouraged anyone to vote for the feature, and the linked content isn't a question, it's a feature request from a random user.

Comment: @amn: Better now?

Answer (score 7):

There is `chrome://settings`.

It is not a table, as `about:config` in Firefox, it's tabbed, with tree structure. Every settings page has a URI (`chrome://settings/advanced`) and even individual options could be linked – for now only using search and clicking on a section of interest (`chrome://settings/search#sync`).

Comment: Use About:About to access all hidden pages in Chrome.

Comment: this is, as of the current date, the same as clicking the wrench icon to get to standard settings.

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing that's exactly identical to Firefox's `about:config`, but I'm surprised that nobody's mentioned Chrome's `about:flags` feature. You can use this to turn on/off experimental browser features. It doesn't give you the granularity that Firefox provides, but it can allow you to do some cool things.

Comment: Actually, [it was mentioned](http://superuser.com/a/239544/36744)

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/239544/304607 - it was mentioned

Comment: It's mentioned on all but two of the answers.