# Chrome/Chromium extension for advanced configuration

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

[There is no about:config](https://superuser.com/questions/23662/is-there-an-aboutconfig-firefox-in-googles-chrome) in Chrome/Chromium, but *is there an **extension** that opens up more ways to configure the browser*?

Searching for configuration, preferences, etc, in [the extension page](https://chrome.google.com/extensions) gives too many hits to go through manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't. Chromium extensions have so little capability (basically iFrames and UserJS and that's it) that even if someone wanted to, they really couldn't make one.

But all is not lost. Most of Google Chrome's advanced config stuff is done in commandline switches. [Here's](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) a pretty comprehensive list.

Comment: Yeah, I read about someone complaining that with command line switches it is hard to make them stick when you launch Chrome in different ways. I, for one, mostly use an application launcher (gnome-do), but I also double click on files. Well, well, if this is how it is, it is. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need any other extensions when you can use `about:about` or `chrome://about` which reveals all the settings and information available for Chrome?

[image]

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see, those links do not offer the kind of configurability you get with about:config in Firefox (hhttp://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries).